# Regex to strictly match a string containing strings with a separator?

Tags: regex

I have multiple elements **popup**, **email** and **webhook**.
They can come in a string formated like :

```
popup|email|webhook
email|webhook
webhook
email
email|webhook
popup|webhook
popup|email
popup
```

I actually got a regex `^(?:popup){0,1}?\|?(?:email){0,1}?\|?(?:webhook){0,1}?$` but it will match `popup|email|webhook` as well as `popupemail|webhook`.

Is there a way to ensure elements are separated with my separatator `|` ?

I also had `(?>(?>(?>popup\|?){0,1}?email\|?){0,1}?webhook){0,1}?` but this is not a solution obvisously as it will work in one direction only, I'm nearly sure this is easily solvable but I dont know in wich way to look in the Regex world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add word boundaries to make sure that two words are never together.

```
^(?:popup)?\b\|?\b(?:email)?\b\|?\b(?:webhook)?$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uC6yZ1/1)